# Loading string in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

How to load a string like below in UIWebview

```
"\n
\nEgestas rhoncus auctor ac. Risus parturient, mid ultrices nisi.\U00a0
\nAugue ac elementum duis aliquet dolor elementum cum?\U00a0
\nTristique, augue sit lorem adipiscing dis!\U00a0
\nNunc nunc ultricies pellentesque dis dictumst enim
\n
\n"
```

I am trying to load this same content in 5 webviews..But it is crashing for me..

Comment: if u load this string and want to keep the same number of lines u should consider replacing the \n with <br/>

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should use:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil];
```

But note, that you won't preserve line breaks. To preserve line breaks you'll need to replace \n with <\br> (or any valid line breaking html), so this turns into:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score 14):

This is pretty simple As Below,

```
 [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

You can specify the `baseURL` to get relative paths working. Is this what you were looking for ? Or more general explanations about `UIWebView ?`

Answer (score 8):

Here is the Code

```
 NSString* htmlString= @"hereyourSTring";
 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

this would load the String in WEBview.

Comment: But it is crashing for me :(

Comment: @Dev can you crash log here..?

Comment: @Dev i am just asking, put crash log here. if you see your console there would be crash log related to the crash

Answer (score 4):

> In Swift 3

```
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("htmlString", baseURL: nil)
```

But note, that you won't preserve line breaks. To preserve line breaks you'll need to replace \n with <\br> as done by @MANIAK_dobrii in above answer