# How to call javascript code from Objective - C code?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I want to call the following javascript code from my Objective - C code. I have found many answers like [How to call JavaScript Function in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334047/how-to-call-javascript-function-in-objective-c), but none of them met my requirement. Following is my code

```
var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var sc=document.createElement('script');
sc.type='text/javascript';
sc.async=true;
sc.src='https://api.zaakpay.com/zaakpay.js?random=' + Math.random();
s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc,s);


function encryptField(cardvalue) {
        var out = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < cardvalue.length; i++) {
                out += (cardvalue.charAt(i).charCodeAt() + key.charAt(i % key.length)
                                .charCodeAt())
                                + ",";
        }
        return out;
}


function prepareCall(){

   var paymenttype = document.getElementById("paymenttype").value;
   if(paymenttype=='CC' || paymenttype=='DC' || paymenttype=='SC'){
      document.getElementById("cvv").value = encryptField(document.getElementById("cvv").value);
   }
   if(paymenttype=='CC' || paymenttype=='DC' ){
          document.getElementById("ccnumber").value = encryptField(document.getElementById("ccnumber").value);
          document.getElementById("expmonth").value = encryptField(document.getElementById("expmonth").value);
          document.getElementById("expyear").value = encryptField(document.getElementById("expyear").value);
   }
}
```

Can I call the above code directly from my ios code without loading a HTML page? If I need a HTML page to load the script then how I can call the methods as soon as web view is loaded? Also I need to pass some parameters in the prepareCall() method? How I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to learn basic javascript to do it. Currently it is a too broad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your js using

```
[_webView loadHTMLString:@"<script src=\"your.js\"></script>" baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

and then in `webViewDidFinishLoad` you can call function and pass parameters as follows

```
NSString *javascriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourFunction('%@','%@')",firstVar,secondVar];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptString];
```

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked is actually pretty much all you need.  You can load a UIWebView from a string (see [iOS Load UIWebView From String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343794/loading-string-in-uiwebview)), so you could literally create a string with the code you have above and as long as you put it in `<script>` tags it would execute when the UIWebView was loaded.

i.e. (the HTML is maybe too minimal to run, this is really just pseudocode

```
NSString *foo = @"<html><head><script>"
                // Insert your script here
                "</script></head><body></body></html>";
```

However, you really would be better off putting your globally scoped code in a function and calling that as the body's onload handler.

There is however a bunch of other things that you may need to do ... unless all you want to do is display the result as a web page.

P.S.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:foo baseURL:nil];
```